# Necessity of "in" and "the"?

Tags: prepositions, articles

Please let me know which sentence is correct. I have faced the first and third one in the Longman dictionary, but dictionaries are prone to typos and errors. So I couldn't be sure which one is correct and which one is not. Please help me know.

> 1. The verb is **in the** past tense.
> 2. The verb is **in** past tense.
> 3. The verb is past tense.

Comment: the 1st and 3rd examples are correct, with the 1st one being probably the best of the two.

Comment: Only use the third if you want to indicate the verb is in a state of high anxiety.

Comment: In which case, you could also describe it as 'beyond tense'.

Comment: ......elevense?

Comment: All three are fine and understandable. The term "correct" has no value here--for no one is grading or marking the prose, since this is not a school environment.

Comment: All three convey the same meaning, even though the last one implies that `past tense` is an adjective (or even a noun), people will still understand it.  The first option is the optimal one though.

Answer (score 1):

The first is usual; the third is odd, but unambiguous and terse; the second is wrong.

It is most likely that a dictionary would deliberately use the third form for brevity.

Comment: Why is the second wrong? It seems fine to me.